# Is there any way to force g++ to compile this program?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, g++

Making g++ compile things it shouldn't isn't generally a good idea (and I suspect not possible in general), but in this case I'm trying to write static analysis checks to find violations of specific MISRA rules and unfortunately g++ is rather too good :) I'm trying to check a rule which says "A pointer to a virtual base class shall only be cast to a pointer to a derived class by means of dynamic_cast." This is such a sensible rule that g++ checks it itself and fails to compile the following code:

```
class B
{
public:
        virtual ~B() {}
};

class D : public B {};
class VD : virtual public B {};

int main()
{
        D d;
        VD vd;
        B *pd = &d;
        B *pvd = &vd;
        D *d1 = (D*)(pd); // Fine
        D *d2 = static_cast<D*>(pd); // Fine
        D *d3 = dynamic_cast<D*>(pd); // Fine
        D& d4 = static_cast<D&>(*pd); // Fine
        D& d5 = dynamic_cast<D&>(*pd); // Fine
        VD *vd1 = (VD*)(pvd); // Bad
        VD *vd2 = static_cast<VD*>(pvd); // Bad
        VD *vd3 = dynamic_cast<VD*>(pvd); // Fine
        VD& vd4 = static_cast<VD&>(*pvd); // Bad
        VD& vd5 = dynamic_cast<VD&>(*pvd); // Fine
        return 0;
}
```

This makes me feel extremely positive about using g++ as a compiler, but is a bit problematic in this case, because (a) we have to be able to build code in order to analyse it with our tool, and (b) there may well be other compilers that would unhelpfully compile this code, in which case we can't just mark this down as "compiler-checked" in general.

Short of trying to find another compiler that will compile this (which is an option), is there a way of making g++ compile it? I tried `-fpermissive` without success.

Comment: The code is ill-formed. If you find a compiler that accepts it, file a bug :)

Comment: @Mat: The only thing I can think is that MISRA is aimed at people who may be using unusual compilers that do the wrong thing - but in that case I'd be a bit worried if anyone was using such compilers to build safety-critical systems...

Comment: If your static analysis framework doesn't let you mark a check as "done by the compiler" for a specific list of known-good compilers, you should add that feature if you're worried about some day having to deal with a compiler that borks this test. I don't really see what else to say. Patching GCC to add a `-fcompile-wrong-code-please` doesn't seem very productive.

Comment: The C cast is "allowable" (although not nice) and compiles perfectly well with g++, unless you give it some "pedantic" alike commandline option. For the rest, it has already been mentioned that it's not well-formed, so there's no way to make a non-broken compiler accept that.